# All Cauchy sequences in R converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

### **Proposition**: All Cauchy sequences in **R** converge.

**Proof**: 
Let $a_n$ be a Cauchy sequence. Since $a_n$ is bounded, the upper and lower limits

$M = \limsup_{n→∞}(a_n)$
and $m = \liminf_{n→∞}(a_n)$ are finite. 
*(Is this the "first" element in $a_n$? Or the greatest lower bound?)*

It suffices to show that M = m. 
Given an $ε > 0$, there is an N∈**N** such that $|a_n − a_k|<ε$ whenever $n,k≥N$.

In particular, we have $|a_n−a_N|<ε$ for all $n ≥ N$.
*(Where is $a_N$ located?)*

This means that $m_k≥a_N−ε$ and $M_k≤a_N+ε$ for $k≥N$. (How did M and m get the k from? And why?)

Consequently $M_k−m_k≤2ε$ for all $k≥N$ 
Hence $M−m≤2ε$ for every $ε>0$,and this is only possible if $M = m$

**Question**: What was the strategy used here? Informally speaking. What am I missing here?

Comment: Related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325836/proof-that-all-cauchy-sequences-converge?rq=1

Comment: Yes, its pretty related. Only this proof doesnt use the notion of subsequences. This is maybe a more simpler one, only I don't understand the intuitivity of it

Comment: Very confusing. What do you mean with *"first" element* and *Where is $a_N$ located*? What is $M_k$, $n_k$?